# maven dependency plugin not taking changes in pom

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

I am using maven dependency plugin in my pom, and this is the how I configured it:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>analyze</id>
<!--                        <id>my-dependency-analysis</id>-->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
<!--                    <usedDependencies>-->
<!--                        <usedDependency>com:test-client</usedDependency>-->
<!--                    </usedDependencies>-->
                    <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
                    <ignoreNonCompile>true</ignoreNonCompile>
                    <ignoredUsedUndeclaredDependencies>
                    </ignoredUsedUndeclaredDependencies>
                    <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
                        <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>com:boot-client:*</ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>
                    </ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I previously configured an id named my-dependcy-analysis but as you can see I commented it, the problem here is that I tried to run mvn install several times, and I'm still getting in the log the same commented id!

Even if I set the failonwarning flag to false I am getting build failure, it is like the changes are not being taken!

Error log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:analyze-only (my-dependency-analysis) @ MyTest ---
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    com:test-client:jar:v1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Comment: Full pom file, full log output, Maven version, JDK version, the maven-dependency-plugin. version is a bit out of date https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ ...

Comment: for confidentialty I can't put the full pom, as for the maven version maven-3.6.2-takari, for java jdk 11, the warning is the full log the rest of the log is info not related

Comment: What is `maven-3.6.2-takari`? apart from 3.6.x is a bit old.. without the pom file it's more or less impossible to gues what might be the issue...

Comment: I figured it out, the problem is the settings I'm putting where override by the parent pom.